# Why does my camera-text parenting function in viewport mode and not in the animation render?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, camera, parent, text-object

I'm trying to parent two different text-objects to a moving camera so that they move at the same rate as the camera and appear as if they aren't moving. In the viewport, everything works as I want it to. However, when I render my animation, the text-objects act like they don't have a parent and simply drift off the screen. The camera is the only object with motion related keyframes.

Here is the link: [image]

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities and I couldn't guess on this little information. Could you include a blend file that shows this?  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: I added it. The two text-objects that I want are "Depth Text" and "Pressurized Text"

Comment: In 2.92.2, both viewport mode and animation render the text stay with the camera.

Comment: I updated my blender from 2.90.1 to 2.93.2 and my problem has been solved. Thank you!